# Can an IndexedDB key of type "String" be a url path?

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I want to use urls as keys for storing data in an IndexedDB. I think this is a valid key (from reading this: http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#key-construct ) but am not 100% certain. Are the following valid keys?

```
//Examples of storing keys
objectStore.put( data, "http://example.com/some-url" );
objectStore.put( data, "http://example.com/some-url#s?e=t%20something&%20=%@" );
objectStore.put( data, "/some-url-relative-url/audio.mp3" );
objectStore.put( data, "/images/test.jpg" );
```

Are there restrictions on the characters that can be in a key if it's a string?

Comment: As per me, there is no restriction as such, you can use any valid Unicode character but I would recommend putting and then trying to retrieve, if retrieval works then you can be sure that everything will work ..

Comment: @hagrawal what do you mean "as per me"? from your experience? or did you help write the spec? thanks!

Comment: "As per me" - means AFAIK. No. No. Np!

Comment: Why don't you give a try putting characters from Unicode supplementary plane, if it works then it means it works. A question is not required for things which can be tried and tested !!!

Comment: @hagrawal i will by that means testing it on every browser that has indexeddb because they don't all implement it the same

Comment: "*they don't all implement it the same*" ?? You means all browsers don't implement IDB ??

Comment: @hagrawal no, i mean the browser's that do have IDB don't all follow the same rules. iOS safari and IE are the worst offenders

Comment: IDB specs doesn't specify any encoding or character set details, but it says that it should be a valid literal as per ECMAScript [ECMA-262], so it would depend upon how each browser is encoding the characters, if you test on one browser, you can fairly assume that it will work on other as well because there shouldn't be differences based on supported encoding and character set. Anyways all browsers supports all Unicode characters. In any case, based on example URLs you have provided, I don't see any character beyond ASCII set, Unicode's BMP is a far question. So, as per me (AFAIK), test it!!!!

Answer (score 3):

All strings can be keys, unless you hit a memory limit or browser bugs.

This includes things like:

```
"" // empty string
"abc\u0000def" // embedded null
"\uD834\uDD1E" // UTF-16 surrogate pair
"\uFFFF" // non-character
"\uD800" // lone UTF-16 surrogate
```

So yes, stringified URLs are valid keys. Of course, they will be compared as strings (sequences of 16-bit code units) so you may want/need to perform URL normalization first, depending on your use case.